# proof about triangles with sides in arithmetic progression

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, alternative-proof

$\require{cancel}$

> The sides of a triangle are in an arithmetic progression with $k>0$ and $a>b>c$. Prove that
>
> 1. $\tan\left(\frac{\hat{A}}{2}\right)\tan\left(\frac{\hat{C}}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{3}$
> 2. if $r$ is the radius of inscribed circle, then $r=\frac{2k}{3\left[\tan\left(\frac{\hat{A}}{2}\right)-\tan\left(\frac{\hat{C}}{2}\right)\right]}$.

My proof:

Let $\hat{A}=\alpha,\hat{B}=\beta,\hat{C}=\gamma,\overline{AB}=c,\overline{AC}=b,\overline{BC}=a$ and $r$ is the radius of the inscribed circle.

Let $s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$ and $A$ the area of the circle. We know from some theorems that

> $A=sr$
>
> $A=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$.

From this we can conclude that

$$\begin{align}
sr&=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}\\
s^2r^2&=s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)\\
r^2&=\frac{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}{s}\\
\frac{r}{(s-a)(s-c)}&=\frac{s-b}{sr}
\end{align}$$

From some unknown theorem we know that

> $r=\frac{s-a}{\cot\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}=\frac{s-b}{\cot\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right)}=\frac{s-c}{\cot\left(\frac{\gamma}{2}\right)}$.

Since $\cot\theta=\frac{1}{\tan\theta}$, and since in an arithmetic progression with $a>b>c$ and $k>0$ we gets $a=b+k,c=b-k$

$$\begin{align}
\tan\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)&=\frac{r}{s-a}\\
\tan\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right)&=\frac{r}{s-b}\\
\tan\left(\frac{\gamma}{2}\right)&=\frac{r}{s-c}.
\end{align}$$

Then

$$\begin{align}
\tan\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\tan\left(\frac{\gamma}{2}\right)&=\frac{r^2}{(s-a)(s-c)}\\
&=\frac{\cancel{(s-a)}(s-b)\cancel{(s-c)}}{s}\frac{1}{\cancel{(s-a)(s-c)}}\\
&=\frac{s-b}{s}\\
&=\frac{\frac{a+b+c}{2}-b}{\frac{a+b+c}{2}}\\
&=\frac{\frac{b+\cancel k+b+b-\cancel k}{2}-b}{\frac{b+\cancel k+b+b-\cancel k}{2}}\\
&=\frac{\frac{b}{2}}{\frac{3b}{2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{3},
\end{align}$$

which proves part 1. For 2 we have

$r=\frac{2k}{3\left[\tan\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)-\tan\left(\frac{\gamma}{2}\right)\right]}\iff\tan\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)-\tan\left(\frac{\gamma}{2}\right)=\frac{2k}{3r}$

we have that

$$\begin{align}
\tan\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)-\tan\left(\frac{\gamma}{2}\right)&=\frac{r}{s-a}-\frac{r}{s-c}\\
&=r\left(\frac{1}{s-a}-\frac{1}{s-c}\right)\\
&=\frac{r[(s-c)-(s-a)]}{(s-a)(s-c)}\\
&=\frac{r(a-c)}{(s-a)(s-c)}\\
&=\frac{(s-b)(a-c)}{sr}\\
&=\frac{a-c}{3r}\\
&=\frac{(b+k)-(b-k)}{3r}\\
&=\frac{2k}{3r},
\end{align}$$
which ends the second part.

- Is my proof correct?
- What can I improve?
- Is there another way to prove this?

Comment: Looks good to me, though I didn't check the details. The unknown theorem may be called: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cotangents